# jQuery .validate initial label text

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

hi i was wondering how can i make for once the field is validate to show initial text in label:

jQuery:

```
$("#contact").validate({
  rules: {
    con_name: {
      required:true,
      minlength:3
    },
  }  
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="con_name" id="con_name" />
    <label for="con_name" generated="true" class="error">Insert Name</label>
</form>
```

The text `Insert Name` is replaced with the error message but upon success it hides the label and erases the initial text `Insert Name`.  I need it to show again the initial text.

Answer (score 0):

Set the messages like I show:

Set like this:

```
$("#contact").validate(
    {       
    rules:{
        con_name:{required:true, minlength:3},                      
          }  
    messages: {
          con_name: 'Insert Name'
          }

    });
```

Comment: that dosnt work it replaces all the error messages and it also keeps hiding the text when succes

Comment: You seem to be missing a comma before `messages`.

Comment: The plugin has several options that let you control how validation errors are displayed. See the examples on the documentation page.